# No entiendo porque me devuelve undefined cuando debería devolver el array

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de que esta función me devuelva un array en el cual cada elemento debería ser un par de string, en este caso debería retornar algo así:

```
['me',' l','la','mo',' J','ua','nM','a_'];
```

Pero al llegar al final, me dice que nueva es `undefined` y me trae ese resultado.

```
let str = 'me llamo JuanMa';

function solution(param){
 const arr = [];
 let work=param; 
 if(param.length%2==1) {
   work = param + '_';
 }
 function recur(elemento){
 if (elemento=='') {
   return arr;
 }
 arr.push(elemento.slice(0,2));
 let nueva = elemento.substring(2);
 recur(nueva);  
}
recur(work);
}

solution(str);
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo estás retornando el valor de `solution`? ;)

Comment: Hola.. muchas gracias, justo me di cuenta hace un rato y vine a ver que onda... Mi problema es que no sé cuando poner el return, muchas veces cambia los valores como quiero pero a la hora de llegar al final de la recursión y devolver los valores que quiero, me trae undefined o el rtdo de la primera ronde de la recursión...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu función no estás retornando nada, por eso que te devuelve `undefined`, tendrías que agregar los `return` y listo:

```js
let str = 'me llamo JuanMa';

function solution(param) {
  const arr = [];
  let work = param;
  if (param.length % 2 == 1) {
    work = param + '_';
  }
  function recur(elemento) {
    if (elemento == '') {
      return arr;
    }
    arr.push(elemento.slice(0, 2));
    let nueva = elemento.substring(2);
    return recur(nueva); // agrego el return aquí
  }
  return recur(work); // agrego el return aquí
}

console.log(solution(str));
```